# How to lint Terraform files

Tags: terraform, lint

I need to enable TLS 1.1 or above in Terraform files, and I need a linter for this. Basically I have the following:

```
origin_ssl_protocols   = ["SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
```

Any other TLS version should fail the build.

I'm really lost as to how to go about this. Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give it a stab with the limited context here.

In Terraform 13 variable validation was introduced which allows you to do something like this.

```
variable origin_ssl_protocol {
  type = string
  description = "Words" 
  
  validation {
    condition = can(index(
      ["SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"], 
      var.origin_ssl_protocol))
    error_message = "Invalid SSL Protocol" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - this is exactly what I was looking for.

I asked a similar question which you might be able to help with too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048457/terraform-list-b-can-only-have-entries-from-list-a