# Terraform list B can only have entries from list A

Tags: terraform

I have the following validation:

```
variable origin_ssl_protocol {
  type = list(string)
  description = "Words" 

  validation {
    condition = ???
    error_message = "Invalid SSL Protocol" 
  }
}
```

In the condition I want to compare 2 lists. **List B can only have entries that are in List A**.

Examples:

```
List A: ["TLS1", "TLS2", "TLS3"]
List B: ["TLS1"]
# IS VALID - list B only has entries which are in List A

List A: ["TLS1", "TLS2", "TLS3"]
List B: ["TLS1", "TLS1.1"]
# IS INVALID - List B has an entry which is not in List A
```

What would the above condition be for this? Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

I think it should be something like the following, however this doesn't work:

```
variable origin_ssl_protocol {
  type = list(string)
  description = "Words"

  validation {
    condition = for protocol in var.origin_ssl_protocol :  
      can(index(
      ["SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"],
      protocol))
    error_message = "Invalid SSL Protocol."
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can yet validate a collection type variable. See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24223 for an issue tracking it as a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic i could think of:

This equation satisfies your requirement:
Unique values of (List A + List B) would be same as (List A) --- OK condition

In case, List B has extra elements that List A does not have, then Unique values of (List A + List B) would greater than List A --- NOT OK condition

With a combination of Concat, toSet, Length functions, below scary looking condition should work i guess... check it out..

```
variable origin_ssl_protocol {
  type = list(string)
  description = "Words"

  validation {
    condition = (length(["SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"])==length(toset(concat(["SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"],var.origin_ssl_protocol))))
    error_message = "Invalid SSL Protocol."
 }
}
```

I tested for these values...

```
#origin_ssl_protocol = ["TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1"]   --> OK
#origin_ssl_protocol = ["TLSv1","HELLO"]                 --> NOT OK
#origin_ssl_protocol = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3"]   --> NOT OK
#origin_ssl_protocol = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1"]              --> OK
#origin_ssl_protocol = ["SSLv3"]                         --> OK
#origin_ssl_protocol = ["sSLv3"]                         --> NOT OK. case.
```

Note: Its case sensitive... If you need it to be case insensitive, then apply lower or upper function.

Answer (score 1):

In Terraform 13 variable validation was introduced which allows you to do something like this.

```
variable origin_ssl_protocol {
  type = string
  description = "Words" 

  validation {
    condition = can(index(
      ["SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"], 
      var.origin_ssl_protocol))
    error_message = "Invalid SSL Protocol" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think of what you are describing as a set operation: subtracting the set of valid values from the user's given set should produce an empty set.

The Terraform function for set subtraction is [`setsubtract`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setsubtract.html), and our condition here would be to call that function and then require that the result has length zero:

```
variable "origin_ssl_protocol" {
  type = list(string)

  validation {
    # If any elements of var.origin_ssh_protocol are not
    # in this set of valid values, the length of the
    # result will be greater than zero.
    condition = length(setsubtract(
      var.origin_ssh_protocol,
      ["SSLv3", "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"],
    )) == 0
    error_message = "Invalid SSL Protocol."
  }
}
```

If you're going to be using this value in a context where the order doesn't matter, I'd recommend declaring it as `set(string)` instead so that it's clearly defined as being an unordered set rather than an ordered sequence, but I left it as `list(string)` here to match your example.

Comment: The issue here is that var.origin_ssl_protocol is a list too. As far as I understand "contains" works when checking with a list and a string variable only.

Comment: oh hmm I saw `type = string` in your original example and thought that's what you were trying to do. I'll try to rewrite this for `list(string)` but in order for the question and answer to make sense once I do I'd ask you to also edit your question so the first example says `type = list(string)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - I missed that one. I now edited the question so it's type = list(string) instead :)

Comment: I don't think setsubstract works because the user can specify only a single protocol too. Look at my example section in the question.